# How to convert the local time into utc time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utc, python-datetime

I am trying to convert the local time into UTC time. But getting the below error.

`Error: an integer is required (got type str)`

```
from datetime import datetime

starts_date = '2021-07-30 09:30:00'(timestamp without time zone)

ts = starts_date
x = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
x_ts = x.timestamp()
```

Comment: Please update to show the assignment of `starts_date`.

Comment: change `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)` to just `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)`

Comment: @po.pe an integer is required (got type str) error throwing

Comment: @match You cannot feed `utcfromtimestamp` with just a string that looks like a timestamp and expect the function to understand what you want it to do. You need to feed in an actual `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that datetime is imported correctly as `from datetime import datetime`. Can be a bit confusing but the method `utcfromtimestamp` belongs to `datetime.datetime` and not `datetime` itself.

Comment: added datetime.datetime and imported the correctly still getting the issue

Comment: once you have imported it correctly, you should use just `x = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)`

Comment: an integer is required (got type str) throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example to convert a timestamp of (now) to a UTC timestamp.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Create a timestamp object for now.
ts = dt.timestamp(dt.now())

# Convert now to a UTC timestamp.
dt.utcfromtimestamp(ts).timestamp()

>>> 1627637013.657752
```

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` takes an integer that represent the amount of seconds passed since January 1st 1970.
This means with

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
print(dt.utcfromtimestamp(0))
```

you get

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```